# drawing the polygon

Tags: area, polygons

I want to draw the polygon, its sides and area is provided.
e.g.
 number of sides : 4
     length of 1st side : 1
     length of 2nd side : 2
     length of 3rd side : 3
     length of 4th side : 4
     area of polygon : 4.898979
please guide me how to draw the shape of the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option:

Label the vertices in the following way: the first vertex is the intersection of edges 1 and 4, the second vertex is the intersection of edges 1 and 2, and so on.  Consider a diagonal of the quadrilateral, i.e., an edge between the first and third vertices.  This makes two triangles (provided the quadrilateral is convex).  Now, call $t$ the length of this diagonal, you can use [Heron's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronsFormula.html) to compute the area of the triangles and solve for $t$.

If you assume that $4.898979$ represents $\sqrt{24}$, then I plugged this into Maple and found that the diagonal described above is $\sqrt{385}/7$ (which is not a particularly useful answer, but it can be used to draw the quadrilateral.